# how to pass custom parameter in facebook sharer link

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-sharer

**Code 1:**

```
<a id="button" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank">
<script>
    function fbs_click() {
        u=location.href;
        t=document.title;           
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),
                'sharer',
                'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');

            return false;
        }
```

Here Title "t" is not working but i want to display custom **title, summary, url and image** so, I tried something like this

**Code 2:**

```
<a id="button"          href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?
                        s=100
                        &p[url]=<?php echo $pressurl;?>
                        &p[images][0]=http://myurl/images/linkedin_image.png
                        &p[title]=mytitle
                        &p[summary]=containsummary                      ">
```

In both the cases nothing happened it automatically get some content (title,image,summary) from the above mentioned url and I want to display custom title,image and summary in facebook share page and i dono how to use og meta tag and **what s=100 it means?**..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using the sharer.php script on Facebook, you can use the Facebook JavaScript SDK to make a custom share dialog.

```
<!-- include Facebook JavaScript SDK -->

<!-- share link -->
<a href="#" class="share-btn">Share to Facebook</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fb_share() {
    // facebook share dialog
    FB.ui( {
        method: 'feed',
        name: "Your Page Title",
        link: "https://www.webniraj.com/link-to-page/",
        picture: "https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/557969.png",
        caption: "Some description here"
    }, function( response ) {
        // do nothing
    } );

}

// add click event to link using jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.share-btn').on( 'click', fb_share );
});
</script>
```

This will create a nice popup for sharing to Facebook, and you can easily change the title, description, and picture attributes in the JavaScript. [Working demo available here](https://www.webniraj.com/2013/05/11/facebook-api-tracking-shares-using-the-javascript-sdk/).

Comment: Demo doesn't work - "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains"