# Passing title, url and image on share.php of facebook

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I want to share title , image and description on facebook without javascript just by passing these to share.php of facebook.
I got some code on this site in question [Open source alternative to AddThis AddToAny, ShareThis etcfor Social Bookmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074566/open-source-alternative-to-addthis-addtoany-sharethis-etcfor-social-bookmarking)

and I have read the question [how to pass custom parameter in facebook sharer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653745/how-to-pass-custom-parameter-in-facebook-sharer-link)

Now I want to combine both questions. Can I pass Image, title and description simply in the facebook share.php url

like:

```
<a class="scmFacebook" href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>'>Facebook</a>
```

OR
If I am wrong then please show me the right destination.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the facebook developers ([bug](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/357750474364812/)):

> The sharer will no longer accept custom parameters and facebook will pull the information that is being displayed in the preview the same way that it would appear on facebook as a post from the url OG meta tags.

1. Either you use the [Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/) - requires Javascript SDK
2. Or, use the latest [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog)  - requires just an app id. It has a direct url direction method for invoking the share dialog:

   ```
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
     app_id={app-id}
     &display=popup
     &href={link-to-share}
     &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
   ```

Comment: what about this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/photo/   I didnt understand what it is saying?

Comment: What about it? Its a complete different API `/photo-id`, it has nothing to do with the sharing!

Comment: ok! and i have problem while using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog as you give will you please help me!

Comment: Please post a separate question explaining your problem and code. :)

Comment: One last thing, before leaving this question page, Can you please tell how he is doing this- https://www.webniraj.com/2013/05/11/facebook-api-tracking-shares-using-the-javascript-sdk/ and can I implement this one in my site- http://www.ididthisfilm.com/lex_tmp2/us_portfolio/week-1/.

Comment: He's using the deprecated Feed Dialog (using Javascript SDK). Its new form is the Share Dialog that I've mentioned in the answer.  You can check the source code of http://jsbin.com/egatas/latest , the script loads the jfacebook javacript sdk and then uses feed dialog. But I suppose you are looking for a method that dont uses javascript sdk right?

Comment: Can anyone tell me where to put the code that @SahilMittal has mentioned in the answer. I mean where as in jquery or html url?

Comment: You an use the link as `<a>` href's

Answer (score -1):

```
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="image_link" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.google.com/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Google" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=link">Facebook</a>
</body>
```

Use meta property to use title description and image and link sharer.php to share