# folder image share on facebook gives error 'href should represent a valid URL'?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sharer, facebook-share, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I have a image temp/example.png in my local project folder. I would like to share this image on my facebook timeline using facebook's php sdk. I found this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322221/passing-title-url-and-image-on-share-php-of-facebook) 
. So, I formed my share post url string as given below:

```
var $shareUrl=https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=xxxxxx&display=popup&href=https://localhost/PhpProject1/temp/example.png&redirect_uri=https://localhost/PhpProject1/success.html';

 echo '<a href="'.$shareUrl.'"><button  style="width:70%;background-color:#4267B2;color:white;border:none;height:35px;">Share on Facebook</button></a>';
```

Then I called this url on button click but, I got 'href should represent a valid URL' error. Here PhpProject1 given in url is php project on my system. I tried to solve this but, not succeeded. So, pleas help me in solving this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The redirect_uri should be equal (or relative) to the Site URL

Comment: Thansk for reply, my redirect_uri is [https://localhost/PhpProject1/success.html] is relative to my site url [https://localhost/PhpProject1] already :(

Comment: I also would like to know whether giving href url as local url like href=https://localhost/PhpProject1/temp/example.png is right?

Comment: maybe it is not